# 2Checkout payment - show a product's title in a cart view

Tags: 2checkout

I've implemented 2Checkout Hosted Payment option on my site and now I'd like to see a product's title in a 2Checkout cart page. I can see Totals only at the moment. I pass all the parameters needed, such as:

```
input type="hidden" name="li_0_type" value="product"

input type="hidden" name="li_0_name" value="Currency Automatic Switcher plugin for VirtueMart"

input type="hidden" name="li_0_quantity" value="1"
```

But I still can't see the product's title. I contacted their support - no result.

How can I show products titles?

Answer (score 0):

The following should help you accomplish displaying product names at checkout:

```
<form action='https://www.2checkout.com/checkout/purchase' method='post'>
<input type='hidden' name='sid' value='XXXXXXXXX'>
<input type='hidden' name='mode' value='2CO'>
<input type='hidden' name='li_0_type' value='product'>
<input type='hidden' name='li_0_name' value='Currency Automatic Switcher plugin for VirtueMart'>
<input type='hidden' name='li_0_quantity' value='1'>
<input type='hidden' name='li_0_price' value='1.00'>
<input type='hidden' name='li_0_tangible' value='N'>
<input name='submit' type='submit' value='Checkout' >
```

Please replace the sid parameter X's with your actual 2Checkout account number.